# Get X509Certificates from smart card without authentication

Tags: java, x509certificate, smartcard, pkcs#11

I want to retrieve the list of X509Certificate from my smart card without logging in (without PIN).

My code is the following:

```
    String conf = args[0];
    Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(conf);
    Security.addProvider(p);

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");

    1) ks.load(null, null);
    2) ks.load(null, "".toCharArray());
```

The first test (1) fails with this StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: load failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:763)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at TestPKCS11.main(TestPKCS11.java:29)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: no password provided, and n
o callback handler available for retrieving password
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1184)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.login(P11KeyStore.java:849)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:751)
```

The second (2) fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: load failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:763)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at TestPKCS11.main(TestPKCS11.java:30)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1238)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.login(P11KeyStore.java:849)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:753)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_PIN_INVALID
        at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Login(Native Method)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1222)
```

My config is the following:

```
name=SmartCard
slotListIndex = 0
library=C:\gclib.dll
attributes(*,CKO_PUBLIC_KEY,*)={ CKA_TOKEN=true }
```

NB: I have a local tool (Classic Client ToolBox) that does not require the PIN to display the certificates.

Comment: I found two options to resolve this issue :
1.  Use the MSCapi. Cons: This only works with Windows machines, Pros: no custom dev to add, and it works for any smart card
1. Use the smart card driver. Cons: The development can be tricky and we have to have an implementation for each smart card provider / driver. Pros: Works for any OS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Sun's provider always calls Login, no matter if you want to login or not. Frankly speaking, it can be that the only option is to change the approach, e.g. use some other way to access PKCS#11 devices (we have such mechanisms in our SecureBlackbox, for example).

On the other hand, possibility to retrieve information without logging in to the device, is a kind of information leak, and as such possibility to obtain the list or the certificates themselves depends on the particular device. What works on your device might not work on other devices.